# Node Tabs in Drupal 7

Tags: tabs, drupal-modules, drupal-7

Can someone point me out a module for creating tabs in node?

I already try the QuickTabs but it uses the same tabs in all nodes i want to create different tabs in every node.

I found out that there has been Multigroup module which supported grouping CCK fields and repeating them but there isnt any version for drupal 7

I tried Node reference module but it only shows Links of referenced module not the whole content.

Can someone point me ideas on how to accomplish this maybe views can help some how but i dont know how to reference view with node.

Answer (score 0):

Quicktabs will work fine, just override the look of the tabs with css and or `tpl.php` theme override files.

Or set up lots of different quicktabs and give them each a different display style, there are quite a few built in, and you can specify your own.

Or you could look at jQuery UI Tabs and use built in theme settings...